# how to make nested array objects in javascript in a key value pair format

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array data=[
{
"id":1,
"name":"john",
"income":22000,
"expenses":15000
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"kiran",
"income":27000,
"expenses":13000
},
{
"id":1,
"name":"john",
"income":35000,
"expenses":24000
}
]
```

> i want to make a new array set in following format which is in a key value pair. ie result set.
> can you please explain the best method. ? how to achive using foreach.?

> > tried using foreach method by looping each element. but cant get the desired output format

```
var result= [ {
      "name": "john",
      "series": [
        {
          "name": "income",
          "value": 22000
        },
        {
          "name": "expenses",
          "value": 15000
        },
       
      ]
    },
{
      "name": "kiran",
      "series": [
        {
          "name": "income",
          "value": 27000
        },
        {
          "name": "expenses",
          "value": 13000
        },
       
      ]
    }]
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Comment: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) might be a good place to start

Comment: there are 2 `john`s what about the other one?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your array
const result = [
  {
    name: "john",
    series: [
      {
        name: "income",
        value: 22000,
      },
      {
        name: "expenses",
        value: 15000,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "kiran",
    series: [
      {
        name: "income",
        value: 27000,
      },
      {
        name: "expenses",
        value: 13000,
      },
    ],
  },
];

// What is .map function?
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

// Output

// map return a new function.
// it's a loop method but more equipped
result.map((item, index) => {
  const seriesKeyValues = {};
  // forEach is too, it's a loop method.
  // but not have a return value,
  // just loops and give you item on each loop
  item.series.forEach(serie => {
    //seriesKeyValues is a object.
    // different between seriesKeyValues.serie.name
    // it's a bracket notation
    // look this documentation
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names
    seriesKeyValues[serie.name] = serie.value;
  });

  // return new Object
  // ... is 'spread syntax' basically combine objects
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#spread_properties
  // spread syntax is a new way.
  // old way is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

  return {
    id: index,
    name: item.name,
    ...seriesKeyValues,
  };
});
```

I hope it will help :). if you don't understand any lines of code, i can explain

Comment: @saidfurkandize.Thankyou. And   am a beginner. so can you please explain.That will help me alot.